# JAVA: Need help fixing my movie ticket program for class

Tags: java

I am creating a movie ticket program for a class assignment and am having some trouble getting a few things to work.

1. I can't figure out how I am going to calculate the total cost of the tickets the user wants because I don't know how to tell the program to use a different formula for matinee vs evening tickets?
2. I also need to find a way to not allow the user to buy tickets for children if the movie is rated R?

My code is below...

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //initializes variables for the various costs of each ticket
    double adultMatCost = 7.50;
    double adultEveCost = 9.50;
    double childMatCost = 7.00;
    double childEveCost = 7.00;
    double seniorMatCost = 5.00;
    double seniorEveCost = 7.00;

    //introduces the user to the program, creates scanner for program,
    //and asks user to enter their name
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the J-Town Theater.");
    System.out.print("Please enter a name for our transaction records:");
    String name = scan.next();

    //thanks user and asks user which movie they would like to choose
    //assigns a String movie is assigned text based on what the user chose
    //if user enters a value other than 1 or 2 the program terminates gracefully
    System.out.println("Thank you, " + name);
    System.out.println("Which movie would you like to see?");
    System.out.println("[1] My Little Pony (PG)");
    System.out.println("[2] Blade Runner 2049 (R)");
    System.out.print("Enter movie choice: ");
    int movieChoice = scan.nextInt();
    String movie = "";
        if (movieChoice == 1){
            movie = ("My Little Pony");
        }
        else if (movieChoice == 2){
            movie = ("Blade Runner 2049");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("I'm sorry, " + name + ", but that is an invalid choice");
            System.out.println("Goodbye.");
            return;
        }

    //asks user what time they want to see the movie
    //user enters M/m for Matinee and E/e for evening
    //if user enters something besides M/m/E/e the program terminates gracefully
    System.out.println("What time of day would you like?");
    System.out.println("[M] Matinee");
    System.out.println("[E] Evening");
    System.out.print("Enter movie time:");
    String timeDay = scan.next();
    double totalCost = 0;
    String timeDayResult = "";
    double timeDayME = 0;
        if (timeDay.equals("m")){
            timeDayResult = ("Matinee showing");
        }
        else if (timeDay.equals("M")){
            timeDayResult = ("Matinee showing");
        }
        else if (timeDay.equals("e")){
            timeDayResult = ("Evening showing");
        }
        else if (timeDay.equals("E")){
            timeDayResult = ("Evening showing");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("I'm sorry, " + name + ", but that is an invalid choice.");
            System.out.println("Goodbye.");
            return;
        }

    //asks how many tickets they would like and shows the price for each ticket
    //user enters number between 0 and 10 if they enter something besides that
    //the program will terminate gracefully
    //if the movie chosen was rated R no tickets can be sold to children
    System.out.println("How many tickets would you like?");
    System.out.println("Child : $7.00");
    System.out.println("Adult : $7.50");
    System.out.println("Senior: $5.00");
    System.out.print("Enter number of children (0-10):");
    int ticketsChild = scan.nextInt();
        if (ticketsChild >= 0){
            int ticketsChildTotal = ticketsChild;
        }
        if (ticketsChild <= 10){
            int ticketsChildTotal = ticketsChild;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("I'm sorry, " + name + ", but that is an invalid choice.");
            System.out.println("Goodbye.");
            return;
        }
    System.out.print("Enter number of adults (0-10):");
    int ticketsAdult = scan.nextInt();
        if (ticketsAdult >= 0){
            int ticketsAdultTotal = ticketsAdult;
        }
        if (ticketsAdult <= 10){
            int ticketsAdultTotal = ticketsAdult;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("I'm sorry, " + name + ", but that is an invalid choice.");
            System.out.println("Goodbye.");
            return;
        }
    System.out.print("Enter number of seniors (0-10):");
    int ticketsSenior = scan.nextInt();
        if (ticketsSenior >= 0){
            int ticketsSeniorTotal = ticketsSenior;
        }
        if (ticketsSenior <= 10){
            int ticketsSeniorTotal = ticketsSenior;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("I'm sorry, " + name + ", but that is an invalid choice.");
            System.out.println("Goodbye.");
            return;
        }

    //gives a transaction summary for the user showing what movie they want,
    //what time they want, and how many tickets they want total,
    //then the program calculates the total ticket price
    System.out.println("Thank you, Penolope, here is a record of your purchase.");
    int totalTickets = ticketsSenior + ticketsAdult + ticketsChild;
    System.out.println(movie + " (" + timeDayResult + "): " + totalTickets + " tickets total");
    System.out.println("Children: " + ticketsChild);
    System.out.println("Adults: " + ticketsAdult);
    System.out.println("Seniors: " + ticketsSenior);

    double totalMatineeCost = (childMatCost * ticketsChild) + (adultMatCost * ticketsAdult) + (seniorMatCost + ticketsSenior);
    double totalEveningCost = (childMatCost * ticketsChild) + (adultMatCost * ticketsAdult) + (seniorMatCost + ticketsSenior);


    System.out.println("Total cost: $" + totalCost);

}
```

}

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about an actual line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out how I am going to calculate the total cost of the tickets the user wants because I don't know how to tell the program to use a different formula for matinee vs evening tickets?

You already have the costs calculated in two separate variables, so just use a condition to pick which one you need based on the user input.

```
if("Matinee showing".equals(timeDayResult)){
    totalCost = totalMatineeCost;
}else{
    totalCost = totalEveningCost;
}
```

> I also need to find a way to not allow the user to buy tickets for children if the movie is rated R?

Again, use a condition before you ask for the number of children. Something like:

```
if(movieChoice == 2){
    //Set number of child tickets to 0, perhaps inform user they are not allowed to buy child tickets since movie is rated R
}else{
    //ask the user for number of child tickets
}
```

A few final thoughts - you have several bugs in your program. I noticed these, but there are probably more:

- The calculations for total cost are wrong.
- The logic that is validating your user input is wrong.

Make sure you thoroughly test your code.